# Mac app has embedded provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, sandbox, provisioning

When I build my Mac app for the AppStore, it also embeds the provisioning profile, which is optional based on Apple's email. But, since I have a helper application inside my main app, which also embeds the same profile, I get an "Invalid Binary", and the email from Apple says:

> Invalid Provisioning Profile Location - The provisioning profile for
>   your Mac OS X app must be located in the Contents directory of the
>   main app bundle. A provisioning profile is optional, but you cannot
>   submit more than one.

So, it has more than one provisioning profile... How can I disable the helper app project from embedding the provisioning profile in its bundle??

---

**As much as I despise this solution, but you have to play a detective game to find all the provisioning profile and delete them. I deleted the embedded profiles from the app after it was built, all of them (I had a resource bundle, and the provisioning profile was even embedded there!), and submitted........ Works.** Makes you wonder why the hell was the profile embedded in the first place.......

---

When I tried to remove the provisioning profile for the helper app settings, I get this from Apple:

> Invalid Provisioning Profile - The provisioning profile included in
>   the bundle KPTHelper
>   (.../KPTHelper.app) is
>   invalid. (Missing code-signing certificate.) For more information,
>   visit the Mac OS Developer Portal.

Answer (score 3):

You can enter the same Bundle Identifier with your main application but you just pick the option none in signing option for the helper application.

It's in the general tab of your project settings.

Comment: I've never tried without signing the helper application and just entered the same bundle identifier but also selected signing option as none. It worked...

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. I checked the application bundle, the profile is still embedded. I'll update my question with pictures.